# How to run bash on docker container with entry point?

Tags: mysql, docker

How can I run bash on a container with an ENTRYPOINT?

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash \
    && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
    && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  \
    && nvm i 8.11 \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-server=5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 python3 python3-pip  \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip \
    && pip install awscli --upgrade --user \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENTRYPOINT [ "/etc/init.d/mysql", "start" ] 

EXPOSE 3306
```

I tried:

```
 jiewmeng@JM  ~/Dropbox/ci-docker-node-mysql  docker run -it ci-docker-node-mysql bash
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                        No directory, logging in with HOME=/
                                                                         [ OK ]
 jiewmeng@JM  ~/Dropbox/ci-docker-node-mysql 
```

But I got kicked out once MySQL starts

---

I tried running my docker container ...

```
jiewmeng@JM  ~/Dropbox/ci-docker-node-mysql  docker run -p 3307:3306 ci-docker-node-mysql
✘ jiewmeng@JM  ~/Dropbox/ci-docker-node-mysql  mysql -h 127.0.0.1:3307
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3307' (2)
```

But seems like I cannot connect. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to launch the container using bash:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" ci-docker-node-mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

Your container exits when the command `mysql` completes. Containers don't persist once their task is done.

Try to run MySQL in daemon mode which should prevent it from assuming the process is complete:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mysqld"]
```

EDIT: I took a look at the official `mysql` Docker image and that's how they do it there.

EDIT2: Once that's done, you can run `exec` to get a shell into the container:

```
docker exec -ti container-name /bin/bash
```